# Rotating objects in Garry's Mod

Tags: garrys-mod

Ok, here's a quick and concise question: is there any way to rotate objects you are holding in place with the physics gun? This would be especially helpful in building dupes/maps where I don't want to move my entire character around to get the object I want in place. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The tertiary trigger (USE key, E by default) when held allows the user
>   to rotate the object if grabbed by using the mouse.

*- http://gmod.wikia.com/wiki/Physgun*